# How to do validation in angularjs without Form

Tags: angularjs, validation

My Page doesn't have Form, i want to validate my controls and show validation messages. I can able to see the validation only with forms. How to do the validation without Forms. Appreciate you assistance.

Comment: Please, have a look at "How do I ask a good question?" http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can assign your "submit" button to a function with ng-click, then check all your form values there, show error messages where it corresponds, and then let it submit if everything's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Two-way data binding supported need of you, you don't need form for this. You can hide or show your notification when your condition provided or another cases.

For example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="yourObjectModel">

<div ng-show="yourObjectModel.length < 0" class="alert alert-danger">
   Input must be filled
</div>

<div ng-show="yourObjectModel.length > 15" class="alert alert-warning">
   Your value can't bigger than 15
</div>
```